# What to do with questions tagged "community-wiki"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki

Given the recent change to abolish CW questions, what do we do with these?

1. Remove the tag.
2. Get a diamond mod to convert the question
3. Close the question

Personally I'd prefer 1, which is the policy on Stack Overflow - [Remove the community-wiki tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32947/remove-the-community-wiki-tag)

Comment: Huh? No more CW questions? That will make a LOT of questions off topic/not real.

Comment: @John - I think that was part of the point. The other was that there were increasing numbers of questions converted by accident.

Comment: Sorry, I though you were asking about questions tagged as CW, rather than actual CW questions.

Comment: @John - The question was about tagging, but because of the removal of CW as an option. If you see what I mean.

Comment: CW going away: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were only three, and now there's none.

Comment: Cheers - I would have done it myself straight away, but thought I'd get a 2nd opinion.